# How to get the find bar's last search string in Firefox 25?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I have an extension that uses (abuses?) the `fastFind` interface (essentially the find bar). Specifically, I use the `_find`, and `_findAgain` functions to actually search within a given web page for a given term. My extension needs to keep track of the last performed search, and here's how I did it in Firefox 24 and below:

```
var cachedFindTerm = getBrowser().fastFind.searchString;
```

As of Firefox 25, however, the `fastFind` property no longer seems to exist for the browser object. As such, I have no way to access the find bar's search string. I tried the following, but it returns empty, even after I do a search using the `_find` or `_findAgain` functions:

```
var findBar = getBrowser().getFindBar();
var cachedFindTerm = findBar._findField.value; // This is always blank!
```

Is there a better way to get the previous search string used by the find bar interface in Firefox 25? I sure don't see anything obvious...

Comment: Cannot reproduce, works for me with `gBrowser.getFindBar()._findField.value` (`gFindBar` is shorthand for `gBrowser.getFindBar()`, BTW). Please post a reproducible example and/or steps to reproduce.

Comment: Did you initiate the search solely through the find bar API (i.e. you didn't search through the bar GUI itself)? I'm simply calling `findBar._find(term)` to do the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the "API" (or rather, the private methods, `_` prefixed methods, that aren't guaranteed in any way not to change with any release), the `_findField` will not get updated.

You'll have to put in the new value yourself.

Something along the lines of:

```
gFindBar._find(gFindBar._findField.value = term);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! In the long term, is there a better interface I should be using to programmatically search for text within a page? I don't want to have to write my own search algorithm, but I'm not sure what is publicly available from Firefox.

Comment: Judging from the implementation and from what you're trying to do, I don't think there is a better way or even any official, stable API at all.